Widening the popover for a lightning-datatable editable custom data type to allow a lightning-dual-listbox
The Make a Custom Data Type Editable documentation provides an example of an editable table cell custom type and that example works well.
I'd like to use a Dual Listbox for one column in a table but the fixed width of the popover that hosts the edit markup isn't wide enough; it is using the default popover width of slds-popover_medium. (Though looking at the markup that width looks like it is calculated rather than based on CSS.)
If you have found a way to widen the popover please share. The screen shot below - where the content overflows the popover - is from a Digital Experience where I could hack the CSS but I also need this to work in the normal app.
As I have control of the child markup (the lightning-dual-listbox) the question could be changed to "is there a way to make a position: fixed parent expand to the width of its child in CSS"?

